# Moving rows to bottom of a spreadsheet as titles expire

Tags: google-sheets, row, move

I do the scheduling at a TV station and I have a Google Sheet with a series of programs listed.  As the individual titles expire I have conditional formatting set to turn the row black (they change 30 days from today's date.) I would also like them to move to the bottom of the sheet automatically or quasi-automatically.

Currently, I am doing it manually - Adding row, cutting row, pasting in the new row, and deleting the empty row the data used to be in.  I've done some Googling but hits seemed to all be copying to a new tab or answers didn't work correctly.

This is a small sampling of the full sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UFWl7T3kQDsiGGWEgVl5OyeGC0OarZAbqGSY0I7eMqk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you could achieve a very similar result by adding a new column and filling the column with checkboxes, with a filter you can either hide all rows that are checked (completed) or sort them so they all go to the bottom, this can be automated using a macro, the macro can be bound to a key combination or event set to run on a timer. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Juan, Thanks!  I hadn't thought about hiding the rows, and that might work but would present its own set of challenges.  I do like the idea of creating a macro running on a timer to automatically sort the expired programs to the bottom.  I'll have some time later today or tomorrow to try to set it up.  I might ask more for guidance at that point.